# Why can't ViewController send correct integer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsinteger

I'm developing an application for iPhone.

I wrote this code.

SelectYearTableViewController.m

```
...

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SelectAWeekTableViewController_iPhone *saw = [[SelectAWeekTableViewController_iPhone alloc]init];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [saw makeArray:indexPath.row+1 year:indexPath.section+2008];
}

...
```

SelectAWeekTableViewController_iPhone.h

```
...

- (void)makeArray:(NSInteger)month year:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSLog(@"date%d:%d",month,year);

    ...
}

...
```

I selected second row and first section.

But this application outputs this log.

```
2014-03-29 13:47:13.229 TTManager[5098:60b] date3:2014
```

Why it outputs incorrect integers and what can I do?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Log the values of the index path row and section just before you call `makeArray` as a sanity check.

Comment: Log the `indexPath` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. BTW - why do you create a view controller but never show it?

Comment: Your code is correct.. i used in my demo project, i got correct answer .. problem is else when... my be in system or other..

Comment: Do you have wrong values on 64-bit environment?